# How do I make a 3d array and every row is an np.arange?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I don't understand why this doesn't broadcast:

```
import cupy as cp

popSize = 100
features = 426
maxDepth = 2

featureLoc1 = cp.zeros(shape=(popSize,features,maxDepth),dtype='int')
featureLoc1[:,:,:] = cp.arange(0,features,1)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100, 426, 426), (100, 426, 2)
```

Isn't that how I would do it for a 2d array?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can run ourselves. Also give the error that you are getting from your code. Thanks.

Comment: OK I updated it to make it reproducible and added teh error

Comment: what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: A 3-d array, in which every row is [0 1 2 ...features]. So every element is equal to its column number.

Comment: When you say every row, what do you mean? its a 3D array. what is the shape of this output array

Comment: Every row means every row, number of dimensions isn't relevant? Another way of saying it is every element value is equal to its column number.

Comment: are tensors just arrays with more than 2d?

Comment: @lara_toff Saying "every row means every row" doesn't clarify what you mean. What is a "row" and a "column" in 3d? I understand these terms in 2d, but what do you mean by them in 3d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want np.arange broadcasted over the dimensions with 100 and 2 sizes, you can do this -

```
import numpy as np

popSize = 100
features = 426
maxDepth = 2

featureLoc1 = np.zeros(shape=(popSize,features,maxDepth),dtype='int')
featureLoc1[:,:,:] = np.arange(0,features,1)[None,:,None]
```

You can learn more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy).

Broadcasting here would work similar to this example -

[image]

In this case, broadcasting between (100,426,2) and (1,426,1) will result in a (100,462,2) broadcast over the first and last axis.

Comment: do you have a link to where I can learn broadcasting rules

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy`:

```
In [149]: popSize = 100
     ...: features = 426
     ...: maxDepth = 2
     ...: 
     ...: featureLoc1 = np.zeros(shape=(popSize,features,maxDepth),dtype='int')
     ...: featureLoc1[:,:,:] = np.arange(0,features,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-149-232c28d9bf32>", line 6, in <module>
    featureLoc1[:,:,:] = np.arange(0,features,1)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (426) into shape (100,426,2)
```

(100,426,2) is the shape of the target array, `featureLoc`.  (426,) is the shape of the arange.  By the rules of broadcasting that does not work.

`featureLoc1[:,:,:] = np.arange(0,features,1)[:,None]` does work.  Here the RHS is (426,1) shape, which can be broadcast to (1,426,1) and on to the (100,426,2)